# Get Details for Completed Job - JasperServer (REST)

Tags: rest, jasperserver

How would I go about querying `JasperServer` for a job that has already run? I can get the job details for a scheduled job:

```
http://HOST:PORT/jasperserver/rest/job/{JobID}
```

But couldn't find a way to get it for a job that has been completed. If I run that query for a completed job, I get a 404 exception.